# Extracting Column Data from Variable Names in Loop

Tags: r

I have a series of variables in a spread sheet with names made from multiple rules. For simplicity, I have created a test table to try out methods of iterating through variable names.

```
target =c("data_1", "data_1", "data_1", "data_1", "data_2", "data_2", "data_2")
d1_var1 = c(1,3,2,4,7,9,8) 
d2_var1 = c(3,1,3,1,6,7,8)
d3_var1 = c(40,20,10,40,200,300,200)
d1_var2 = c(90,64,24,10,70,70,70)
d2_var2 = c(10,20,15,15,70,40,20)
test = data.frame(target,d1_var1,d2_var1,d3_var1,d1_var2,d2_var2)
```

To determine the variables I have been extracting the second part of all the variables

```
attach(test)
x = names(test)
Key_Pre = "d1_"
d_variables <- grep(Key_Pre, x, fixed=T, value=T)
d_variables = d_variables[substring(d_variables,1,nchar(Key_Pre))==Key_Pre]
d_variables = gsub("d1","",d_variables)#Remove d1 from the start and then there is a list of the variables
```

Then in a `for` loop, I iterate through the prefixes of `"d1","d2"` and try and extract the column data, but this doesn't work.

```
Prefix = c("d1","d2")

for(i in 1:length(d_variables)){        #Iterate through the d1/d2 prefixed variables
    Set_hold = matrix(,nrow=length(target_name),ncol=3) #Holds data for all target_names
    Var_hold = d_variables[i]   #This dummy variable is neccesary when extracting using a list

    for(j in 1:length(Prefix)){ #Iterate through each of the prefixes
        Var_hold_d = paste0(Prefix[j],Var_hold) #This changes the variable name for each day
        Set_hold[,j] <- test$Var_hold_d #The data for each variable on a day is passed into the matrix
    }   
}
```

Is there a way of extracting the values of these columns from reconstructing variable names? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: May have just solved it by simply extracting column data using `z[,Var_hold_d]`, however, I'm happy to leave it open to discussion, and maybe finding a more efficient way of doing this.

Comment: Don't use `attach`. It will only bring pain and sadness. It creates a copy of the data that does not update if you add or change variables. Instead use `with`, which is a temporary and explicit version or just type the full name out (R has tab completion of object names). The method you added in your answer is the way to go in terms of referencing variables, `test[[Var_hold_d]]` also works

Comment: @Imo This explains some issues I've had with `attach` in past scripts. I will heed your wisdom, and set about `with`ing all my past functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

test[,Var_hold_d] may do it, but I'm sure there's a more efficient way of sorting and carrying out the entire process.